# Error calculation in sklearn dictionary learning

Tags: python, dictionary, scikit-learn

I'm trying to recalculate the reconstruction error of a dictionary learning.

When recalculating this error according to the formula here, I get different results than what sklearn outputs.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.DictionaryLearning.html

From what I could understand in sklearn's code, it may have something to do with the choice of transform_algorithm, but I don't understand what exactly.

Here is a code snippet that illustrates the problem.

https://gist.github.com/nicofarr/d277fb0c350849e0c3333767b8a1fb2b

When setting alpha to 0, my error calculation is correct, so I assume that I'm calculating residuals the correct way. So the problem is with the second term of the error, which involves alpha.

Thanks in advance

Nicofarr

Comment: The example on gist is minimal (one observation as input) but is enough to show the problem. The difference seems to grow larger when increasing the number of observations.

Answer (score 0):

Nico, according to your code you calculate the error using the same formula as in the objective function you minimise to find the best sparse fit, i.e. "residuals"+"alpha*penalty". The penalty is added to enforce sparsity in the solution, but it shouldn't be used to calculate the error. The error that you are looking for is given by the residuals. Have you checked that the optimal parameters (u's and v's) are the same in your code and in sklearn?

Comment: Thanks Yury. Actually, the error given by sklearn includes the penalty ; see here : https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/51a765a/sklearn/decomposition/dict_learning.py#L527 . I am fetching the error from their last iteration.

Comment: It may be silly, but they seem to scale alpha by 1/n_components in their code. If you substitute alpha by alpha/n_comp in your code, will it match?